# Warning about 'Comparison between pointer and integer in C'

Tags: c, csv, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am using file handling in C to open a CSV file, and since I am using windows operating system, the newline character for CSV file is \r\n

```
    if( buffer[i] == "\r\n")
    {
        printf("New line encountered");        
    }
```

But when I am compiling the code, I am getting the error "warning: comparison between pointer and integer". So is there any way to fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
    if (buffer[i]=='\r' && buffer[i+1]=='\n')
```

The above code line has removed the warning, but it is still not detecting the newline

Comment: `if (buffer[i]=='\r' && buffer[i+1]=='\n')`

Answer (score 1):

buffer[i] is a character, and "\r\n" is a string, you can not compare them. If you do, the character will convert to integer, and show the warning you see.

You can use `'\r' == buffer[i] && '\n' == buffer[i + 1]` to compare them, and careful the index edge.

Comment: This has removed the warning, but the program is still not detecting the newline, which is the main aim

Comment: @user2891112 then you can do, use '\n' to split lines, and for every line, delete the last '\r' character if there is. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a single char (`buffer[i]`) with a pointer to a char array (`char* = "\r\n"`). In this case you must check separatelly for `\r` and `\n`. A simple state machine could suffice to that (check that char is \r or \n, and last character is not \r if a \n was found...)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you open the file as a text file instead of a binary file (that is, you use `fopen(filename, "r")` and not `fopen(filename, "rb")`, then the C runtime is required to map the native line endings to Unix-style `\n` line endings.  If you open the file in binary mode, this mapping does not occur.

Consequently, you're not seeing the CR (`'\r'`) characters because the runtime has removed them.  This is why there are so many carefully worded exceptional situations in the C standard describing text streams.  The standard allows for `'\r'`-only line endings (the `'\r'` is mapped to `'\n'`); it allows for fixed length records (trailing blanks are removed; newlines are inserted); it allows for CRLF line endings (the character pair is mapped to `'\n'`); it allows for NL (aka LF) line endings (no mapping is needed).

> #### §7.21.2 Streams
>
> ¶2 A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external representation. Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character. Whether space characters that are written out immediately before a new-line character appear when read in is implementation-defined.
>
> #### ¶7.21.3 Files
>
> ¶2 … Whether a write on a text stream causes the associated file to be truncated beyond that point is implementation-defined.
>
> #### §7.21.9.2 The `fseek` function
>
> ¶4 For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be SEEK_SET.